# Using QuickCheck to test intentional error conditions

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I've seen how QuickCheck can be used to test monadic and non-monadic code, but how can I use it to test code that handles errors, i.e., prints some message and then calls `exitWith`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A disclaimer first: I'm not an expert on QuickCheck and I had no experience with monadic checking before your question, but I see stackoverflow as an opportunity to learn new things.  If there's an expert answer saying this can be done better, I'll remove mine.

Say you have a function `test` that can throw exceptions using `exitWith`.  Here's how I think you can test it.  The key function is `protect`, which catches the exception and converts it to something you can test against.

```
import System.Exit
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Property
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic

test :: Int -> IO Int
test n | n > 100   = do exitWith $ ExitFailure 1
       | otherwise = do print n
                        return n

purifyException :: (a -> IO b) -> a -> IO (Maybe b)
purifyException f x = protect (const Nothing) $ return . Just =<< f x

testProp :: Property
testProp = monadicIO $ do
  input <- pick arbitrary
  result <- run $ purifyException test $ input
  assert $ if input <= 100 then result == Just input
                           else result == Nothing
```

There are two disadvantages to this, as far as I can see, but I found no way over them.

1. I found no way to extract the `ExitCode` exception from the `AnException` that `protect` can handle.  Therefore, all exit codes are treated the same here (they are mapped to `Nothing`).  I would have liked to have:

   ```
   purifyException :: (a -> IO b) -> a -> IO (Either a ExitCode)
   ```
2. I found no way to test the I/O behavior of test.  Suppose `test` was:

   ```
   test :: IO ()
   test = do
     n <- readLn
     if n > 100 then exitWith $ ExitFailure 1
                else print n
   ```

   Then how would you test it?

I'd appreciate more expert answers too.

Answer (score 3):

The QuickCheck `expectFailure` function can be used to handle this type of thing.  Take this simple (and not-recommended) error-handling framework:

```
import System.Exit
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic

handle :: Either a b -> IO b
handle (Left _)  = putStrLn "exception!" >> exitWith (ExitFailure 1)
handle (Right x) = return x
```

and whip up a couple of dummy functions:

```
positive :: Int -> Either String Int
positive x | x > 0     = Right x
           | otherwise = Left "not positive"

negative :: Int -> Either String Int
negative x | x < 0     = Right x
           | otherwise = Left "not negative"
```

Now we can test some properties of the error handling.  First, `Right` values should not result in exceptions:

```
prop_returnsHandledProperly (Positive x) = monadicIO $ do
  noErr <- run $ handle (positive x)
  assert $ noErr == x

-- Main*> quickCheck prop_returnsHandledProperly
-- +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

`Lefts` *should* result in exceptions.  Notice the `expectFailure` tacked on to the start:

```
prop_handlesExitProperly (Positive x) = expectFailure . monadicIO $
  run $ handle (negative x)

-- Main*> quickCheck prop_handlesExitProperly
-- +++ OK, failed as expected. Exception: 'exitWith: invalid argument (ExitFailure 0)' (after 1 test):
```

Comment: Right, but this seems to expect all kinds of failures.  Can we isolate those generated by `exitWith` calls?  Can we assert what the failure code will be?

Comment: @nickie You can add some extra plumbing to the error handling itself if you want to test properties about exit codes.  I.e. have a `determineCode :: Either a b -> ExitCode` function that `exitWith` calls, and make assertions about the behaviour of that.  Don't know if it's possible to go further.

Comment: `expectFailure` seems to pass if any test fails, as opposed to if all tests fail, which is more what I'm looking for.